# BigCommerce PHP hello world app installation error

Tags: php, installation, silex, bigcommerce

I am trying to create a BigCommerce app and used hello world app from here >> https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex

As per its documentation, I have to write localhost URL in callback URL. I have done the same, but when I am trying to install app from my trial store, I am getting error in console and the page shows **installing...**.

Console error is:

> Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://localhost/hello-test/auth/callback?shipping_read_only+store_v2_transactions_read_only+users_basic_information'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Due to this error, I can not install my app and can not start developing on it. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The error seems obvious to me, you have an HTTPS issue. You have to put you website in SSL mode with a certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am just creating app for testing and I have used heroku for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed my issue. I could not find how to start and place the app and coding, but now I found it. Please note my answer.

For https issue in my localhost , I had enabled ssl in php.ini( ubuntu >  /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini >> extension=php_openssl.dll >> uncomment this line). So then I can access my pc using https. Like https://my-pc-ip

Now, we have to just go to Bigcommerce store >> https://devtools.bigcommerce.com/my/apps
Create the app and Save the technical details url with your pc urls,
Now you can install draft apps from your Bigcommerce store.
Do the change in local files and reinstall app. 
If any one can not understand my explanation, then please comment. I am really happy to solve this issue.

For heroku, I quit from it and build the app which I can deploy on my own server.