# Bigcommerce Silex app Error

Tags: heroku, bigcommerce

[BigCommerce PHP hello world app installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404657/bigcommerce-php-hello-world-app-installation-error/44666468)

I am using Heroku for the testing app after many tries of without Heroku app.

But I don't know how to customize pages of the Heroku app?

How can I make changes on heroku app?

Without Heroku, I am getting 2 errors on My Localhost and my localhost already in HTTPS.

Really I am working with the app since last 1 month but I can't not print just Hello World.

In Heroku app, I am getting everything like Client id, Hash code but how to customize Heroku app pages.

Thank you.

Comment: please include the error text you are getting.

Comment: Hi, Alyss just looks your profile it's wonderful.
I want to create an app in Silex or Sinatra.
Here I getting the error of my Silex app 
Error:Error While Loading the Load Callback URL      Link 1) http://imgur.com/KCf2jT7
The folder structure in Localhost.
Link 2) http://imgur.com/UUsUDKz
Dev Tools URL Auth Callback URL and Load Callback URL:
Link 3) http://imgur.com/VP1ThZk
I need help how to get Client ID and Auth secret code and just like get all product data on my home page using my first app.

Comment: Did you complete the setup in the developer/app portal at devtools.bigcommerce.com? It is trying to find routes and failing to get them

Comment: Yes, This procedure already completed. Can you please check this link :
1) imgur.com/KCf2jT7
2) imgur.com/UUsUDKz 
3) imgur.com/VP1ThZk